# Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.1.0.aar

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

After I have updated flutter sdk,
I got this error when I am trying to build the flutter android project

I have updated all firbase packages to the latest version, but nothing happend.
I use these packages:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.4.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.1.0
```

this is the error that appeared to me

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\aliya\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d890e529057a1628855ad6caa6153835\transformed\jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0.
         > C:\Users\aliya\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d890e529057a1628855ad6caa6153835\transformed\jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml
   > Failed to transform play-services-basement-18.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\aliya\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d890e529057a1628855ad6caa6153835\transformed\jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0.
         > C:\Users\aliya\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d890e529057a1628855ad6caa6153835\transformed\jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml
```

please can anyone helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this problem by clean the flutter project and going to `C:\Users\user_name\.gradle\caches` and delete every thing in this folder, then start building my app.

Thanks for me :)